# Should I provide https downloads?

Tags: tls

I've seen several articles like [The sad state of Linux download security](http://worldwidemann.com/the-sad-state-of-linux-download-security/) that suggest you should offer downloads of software updates via https. But is there any point in doing this if your website doesn't require a login to download the update?

Comment: Uh, did you read the page you linked? *"Download page supports HTTPS If this is not the case, none of the provided information is trustworthy to begin with. Everything might be inspected and modified in transit, including download links, checksums, key references and signatures."* A login is not relevant to data integrity.

Comment: Since all this answers are good but a little bit abstract you maybe want to play with tools like [MITMproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), [BDFProxy](https://github.com/secretsquirrel/BDFProxy) and [Ettercap](https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/index.html) to see some of the threats in action.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely there is a point. Properly configured HTTPS includes an [authentication check](https://www.geocerts.com/ssl/understanding_authentication) that ensures that the server is the site you intend. More technically, it confirms that the client-specified hostname (ie: what's in the URL bar for your page) match the name on the SSL certificate. Assuming that a site's private key hasn't been stolen, when you communicate with HTTPS, you know who you are talking to and that there is no man in the middle (MiTM). You have no such guarantee when you are using straight HTTP. You may be talking to an attacker's site or there may be a MiTM modifying what the real site is sending to you.

This HTTPS authentication is the opposite of website authentication as SSL authentication authenticates the server to the client while website authentication authenticates the user to the server. The only time website authentication would be relevant for a download would be if you wished to restrict or otherwise monitor who is performing the download.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @NeilSmithline's answer, TLS (and therefore HTTPS) also includes two features beyond server authentication: encryption (which provides privacy/confidentiality) and integrity (which ensures the data isn't tampered with). Both of these can be very important.

For a download site, the relevance of encryption really just comes down to whether or not the files being offered for download are something that somebody, somewhere, may care whether somebody else downloads. For example, I download a lot of things classed as "hacking tools" because my job requires using such things. Some governments object to people downloading such tools. TLS won't make it impossible to tell I visited the site - I'd use Tor, or something like it, for that - but it could give me plausible deniability about what I downloaded from the site.

Integrity is much more important. While a lot of people don't realize this, encryption by itself does not provide integrity. If there is a man-in-the-middle attacker between me (the client) and you (the server offering downloads), the attacker can modify the contents of my downloads. Depending on the ciphers used, this could potentially even happen if the server is authenticated (the MitM just doesn't interfere with the TLS handshake, but still watches everything) and the network traffic is encrypted (the attacker can flip bits in the ciphertext, especially if you're using a stream cipher or counter-mode block cipher, and you will decrypt the download to be something other than what the server sent). This could, for example, be used to inject malware into your downloads.

You can try to provide integrity without using TLS, by displaying the cryptographic has digest (for example, sha256sum) of your files. In theory, if the server's hash of the files matches the client's hash of the files, then the files haven't been tampered with. In practice, if you aren't using TLS, the client has no way to know what the server's hash of the files is! The attacker can modify the digests the same way they can modify the downloads themselves, so when I hash my download and see that the hash matches, all that this tells me is that the download matches what the attacker meant me to see. (Also, manually checking hashes requires that the user bother to do so, while TLS performs all integrity checks automatically and transparently; you'll never have to do anything or even see it happening unless something tampers with the data.)

Comment: might note that download hashes should be served from a different server than the file. even that's not perfect, but it prevents a one-stop seamless hijack...

Answer (score 0):

Many sites ignore HTTPS while downloading the content from the mirror site. As we know that Mirror sites are useful when the main site is generating too much traffic and the mirror site helps users quickly in getting the content. If the site uses HTTPS in downloading content then there are few benefits leads to users like

- The integrity of the content will enhance, as the content would be downloaded over secured channels with checking the checksum of the content. Many sites like Microsoft deliver secured update for windows over secure channel. Currently, SHA-256 is ideal checksum for encryption. Users get confidence that the content of the download is not altered.
- Using HTTPS on download sites will check download links, checksums, signatures and users will have no excuse of downloading application or other content.
- It is [myth](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/https-site-will-response-very-slow-myths-facts-2/) that HTTPS increases performance overhead, on contrary, the growing ability of computer hardware and software have come down this issue on a nominal stage.
- HTTPS download also ensures that the users are talking to the website that he/she intended to do so. Hence, there is no question of man-in-the-middle attack.

Mostly hackers hide malware in gaming or entertainment site where user’s traffic is much and users always after downloading the content. Few distributions like Fedora, elementary OS offer HTTPS download in a secure environment.

Comment: not very many sites use SPDY or http3, so SSL does have a very real performance impact on site loading, but for downloads, a small initial delay on a single connection is not a big deal. when it's a delay on dozens of bg images and icons and fonts and everything else, site performance can be affected a lot by SSL.